# Getting only a part of a file from Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some very simple sample code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'demo2.htm',
  success: function(loadeddata){
    $("#loaded_data").after(loadeddata);
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Loaded data currently returns everything. What I need to is to get only a specific div and after it add it to #loaded_data.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how jQuery does it internally:

```
$("<div/>").append(loadeddata).find('#mydiv');
```

If you expect to have SCRIPT tags in the HTML, you should throw this in to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE:

```
$("<div/>").append(loadeddata.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, "")).find('#mydiv');
```

**EDIT**:

You are missing the point of what is supposed to be happening.

By doing `$("<div/>").append(...);` jQuery creates a dummy `<div>` and gets the browser to parse the HTML by inserting it inside of the `<div>`. Once that's done, we can find the DIV we want, and return the HTML. So the more proper code sample I should have put above looks like this:

```
var html = $("<div/>").append(loadeddata).find('#mydiv').html();
$('#whereIwantIt').html(html);
```

As you can see in the link, [this does what you want](http://jsbin.com/uzuce).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure what's going on here. But I was unable to get this to work.

http://jsbin.com/avamo

I only want to add #hello to the page. I'm not sure why it turned white after ajax completed. But in the flash there I saw the entire page being added, not just the part I specified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a new pastebin with find and the script problem fixed as Paolo mentioned.

http://jsbin.com/esoze/edit

As you can see the entire HTML of the page is embedded, rather than just the specified element.