# Extract part of HTML document in jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to make an AJAX call to an HTML-returning page, extract part of the HTML (using jQuery selectors), and then use that part in my jQuery-based JavaScript.

The [AJAX retrieval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is pretty simple. This gives me the entire HTML document in the "data" parameter of the callback function.

What I don't understand is how to handle that data in a useful way. I'd like to wrap it in a new jQuery object and then use a selector (via find() I believe) to get just the part I want. Once I have that I'll be passing it off to another JavaScript object for insertion into my document. (This delegation is why I'm not using jQuery.load() in the first place).

The get() examples I see all seem to be variations on this:

```
$('.result').html(data);
```

...which, if I understand it correctly, inserts the *entire* returned document into the selected element. Not only is that suspicious (doesn't this insert the `<head>` etc?) but it's too coarse for what I want.

Suggestions on alternate ways to do this are most welcome.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use your standard selector syntax, and pass in the `data` as the context for the selector. The second parameter, `data` in this case, is our context.

```
$.post("getstuff.php", function(data){
  var mainDiv = $("#mainDiv", data); // finds <div id='mainDiv'>...</div>
}, "html");
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
$(data).find("#mainDiv");
```

Depending on how you're planning on using this, `$.load()` may be a better route to take, as it allows both a URL and a selector to filter the resulting data, which is passed directly into the element the method was called on:

```
$("#mylocaldiv").load("getstuff.php #mainDiv");
```

This would load the contents of `<div id='mainDiv'>...</div>` in `getstuff.php` into our local page element `<div id='mylocaldiv'>...</div>`.

Comment: I would love to use load to hit both the URL and the selector simultaneously, but the insertion into the main document precludes this. I'm hoping the jQuery team will expose the former functionality in a future release!

Comment: Never knew `load()` can load page fragments before. Thanks for the great info.

Comment: If this ever worked before, sadly it doesn't in jQuery 1.9.1 anymore.

Comment: will this load css and scripts tied up/used for this div?

Comment: It's January 2020, and I can do this to load only the "contents" div of an html published Google Doc into a div with id #div1:
`$("#div1").load("https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/{long-assIDstringOfPublishedDoc}/pub #contents");`

Answer (score 6):

You could create a `div` and then put the HTML in that, like this…

```
var div = $("<div>").html(data);
```

...and then filter the data like this…

```
var content = $("#content", div.get(0));
```

…and then use that.

This may look dangerous as you're creating an element and putting arbitrary HTML into it, but it's not: anything dangerous (like a `script` tag) will only be executed when it's inserted *into the document*. Here, we insert the data into an element, but that element is never put into the document; only if we insert `content` into the document would anything be inserted, and even then, only anything in `content` would be inserted.

Comment: -1 The OP requires extracting the part of the document they want _before_ inserting it. Inserting like this could result in inserting a _lot_ of garbage - potentially dangerous garbage - into the page.

Comment: Ah, rats. Sorry, I didn't notice it wasn't being inserted. :( Now I wish I could +1.

Comment: jQuery uses a very similar technique to execute a .load() function (as you've already mentioned) - but it's better to use the technique Resig uses - because it has built in security to block script execution. -> jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML(responseText) ).find(selector) <- Very subtle differences, but the key element here is parseHTML... If content is inserted into the DOM this way, scripts will not be executed - see http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution

Comment: if you don't want to block scripts, you simply have to add a second argument to the parseHTML call -> parseHTML(responseText, true).  Ideally, you'd do this by wrapping the whole block in a function w/optional arguments.  The reason for doing this (in general) is because it gives you an option to enforce security.  If you're worried about the potential for "dangerous content" to be loaded into the div, there's no reason said content could not be inside #content as well.  Or perhaps you just don't want to load scripts (maybe content contains a document.write call or some other async headache).

Comment: @mikeyUX: I don't see the advantage of `parseHTML` if you're okay with scripts in `#content`.

Comment: @icktoofay: I don't see the advantage of assuming you're okay with scripts in #content.. Or that you're always going to be okay with it.  Or that you're always going to be loading from #content.  I'd prefer to create a generic reusable function with appropriate options, but that's just me.

Comment: @mikeyUX: There's nothing preventing you from wrapping what's in my answer into a function, just as there's nothing preventing you from wrapping your method into a function. A possible advantage of keeping scripts in the element is that you might have some page-specific interactions that you'd like to keep in separate scripts. It can be loaded on-demand this way. Of course there are other ways to do it, but this works just as well.

Comment: @icktoofay: however, if I wrap what's in your answer in a function I don't have a practical way of blocking scripts, if that's my prerogative.  when using parseHTML, I have the option of passing a boolean value via the function's arguments to choose whether or not I want to load scripts.

Comment: It's really a moot point, since this is the lowest rated answer... :/

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on a new element, and pass that to a function:

```
function handle(element){
  $(element).appendTo('body');
}

$(function(){
  var div = $('<div/>');
  div.load('/help a', function(){handle(div);});
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubeyu/2

Comment: I think that `$(element).appendTo('body')` can be replaced with `element.appendTo('body')` as `element` is already a `jQuery object`.

Comment: @machineaddict - You are right - it isn't useful in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `dataFilter()` parameter of the `$.ajax` method. It lets you do operations on the results before they are passed out.

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the thing this way

```
$.get(
        url,
        {
          data : data
        },
        function (response) {
            var page_content = $('.page-content',response).get(0);
            console.log(page_content);
        }
    )
```

Here in the console.log you will see the inner HTML of the expected/desired portion from the response. Then you can use it as your wish