# loading page framents with Jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to use $.ajax() to request a page, but load only fragments of that page. I know you can specify what page fragments you want with .load() but I was wondering if this is possible with $.ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 36):

For those of you who are wondering, stoplion is referring to this feature: [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (scroll down on the page):

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. 
>   If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Since $.get() doesn't appear to support it, I assume that $.ajax wouldn't either. A simple way to implement this would be the following:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://example.com/page.html',
   data: {},
   success: function (data) {
      $("#el").html($(data).find("#selector"));
   },
   dataType: 'html'
});
```

This would be the equivalent of

```
$("#el").load('http://example.com/page.html #selector');
```

However, note that the special syntax (' #selector') means that scripts present in the loaded HTML will **not** be executed. See [Script Execution](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) in the .load() docs.

Comment: No, they are not the same. `.ajax()` won't work if `#selector` is at the top level.

Comment: @Derek you're right. Looks like jQuery wraps the response in a `div` and then searches for the selector in that.

Answer (score 3):

You could get your fragment via post, append the html to a div with display: none;  Then use the selector to get the fragment that you want and append it to the region that you wish to display.

Air Code:

```
<div id="tempRegion" style="display:none;">

</div>

$.ajax({
    url: "page.htm",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(results){

        $('#tempRegion').html(results);

        ...

        //  Now select fragment, append to display area
        var fragement = $('#someFragment').html();

        $('#displayRegion').html(fragement);

    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for you is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/page.html',
  data: {},
  success: function (data) {
    $("#el").html($(data).append(data).find("#selector"));
  },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The easy solution with the load method:

```
$("#menu a").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#container").load(this.href + " #container p");
    return false;
});
```

Only use the Ajax method for more complex scripts such as posting or getting from a PHP script or JSON file otherwise it will slow down your website.

Comment: OP already knows it works with `.load()`, and clearly has need of doing it with `.ajax()`, otherwise he wouldn't have asked. Your answer does not address the question, and your links are spammy, as they are not about the topic at hand, either.