# How to load an HTML fragment with JQuery ajax()?

Tags: jquery

Please can someone tell me how to extract the content from a div on another page using the JQuery **ajax() method**?

***anotherpage.html***

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<div id="content">I want to extract this element</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
$.ajax({
url: "anotherpage.html #content",
dataType: "html"
}).done(function(data){
$("#results").html(data);
})
```

But it returns the complete page and not just the #content fragment.

***NOTE: I know how to get it working with the load() shorthand but I'd like to know how to do it with the ajax() method.***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398568/loading-page-framents-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
 $('#results').load("anotherpage.html #content");
```

also visit  "Loading Page Fragments" here [jquery load api](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did mention that I wanted to know how to do it with the full ajax() method and not the load() shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Another shorthand is the [$.get function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and the example relevent to what you are asking is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get#jqxhr-object/). This documentation also gives the expanded form of the method instead of the shorthand.

```
var jqxhr = $.get("example.html", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function() { /* Do work.. */ })
.fail(function() { /* Do error.. */})

// which can be simplified to


$.ajax({
  url: "example.html",
  data: { /*data*/ },
  success: function(oData) { /* Do work.. */ },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

Also, loading content of a page (or Page Fragments) by id can be accomplished by

```
$("#TargetContainer").load("example.html #Content");
```

To do this in a way that the html is not placed on the page :

```
$('<div>').load("example.html #Content");
```

As far as using ajax(), this seems unnecessary except in micro optimization, but I will look into it and check back in

**UPDATE**

The ajax method does not load page fragments. What will have to occur is that in your complete function you will have to :

```
function(oData)
{
    var oContent = $(oData).find('#selector");
}
```

Comment: That's not what's asked here. It's not loading a fragment but the entire document.

Comment: Change the url portion to include a hash tag with the id of the container. I'll update to reflect

Comment: There are some good reasons for using `ajax` rather than `load`: e.g. `ajax.fail()` if something goes wrong is less fiddly than having to examine the `status` and `xhr` params of the `complete` function.  BTW your final function should include sthg like `$( '#existingDiv' ).after ( oContent )`.

Answer (score 0):

Call $.ajax with a 'success' function something like this:

```
function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $('#dialog').html(fragment? $(result).find(fragment).parent().html(): result);
}
```

'fragment' is the jquery selector which in a .load() call would be added to the url, separated by a space.
If 'fragment' is not empty, it creates a jquery object from the content returned and finds the required part using the 'fragment' jquery selector.