# Load part page with jQuery & AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of dynamic links on page A and a div where I wish to load content from another dynamically generated page B based on PHP variables.

```
<a href="loader.php?id=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="loader.php?id=2">Link 2</a>
<a href="loader.php?id=3">Link 3</a>
```

This script successfully loads the external content from the loader.php page using the jQuery script below into `#ajaxContent` div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr("href"),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#ajaxContent").html(response);
            }
        });   
        return false;
    });
});
```

My question is how can I load content from a named div element on the loader.php page using a modification of the script above?
The reason for this is to show the content called using Ajax in its correct context on the natural url eg: href="loader.php?id=2 which is proper non JavaScript enabled / SEO practice I believe.

Update:
Nearly there Explosion Pills ! many thanks.

Working code is.

```
$(".switchMe li a").click(function(){
$.ajax({
url:$(this).attr("href"),
success: function(response) {
//  $("#ajaxContent").html(response);
$("#ajaxContent").html($(response).find("#imageInfo"));
}
});

return false;
});
```

Thanks Jimmy

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading page framents with Jquery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398568/loading-page-framents-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `.load` as in

```
$("#ajaxContent").load($(this).attr("href") + " #named-div");
```

Otherwise, parse the `response` yourself:

```
$("#ajaxContent").html($(response).find("#named-div"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was hacking for a couple of hourse for the correct systax before your help.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `jQuery` [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.