# How to load a specific div/class in a file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, web

I have a file called main.html that contains several div's each with 2 classes:
1st is their specific class 2nd is a class called `menu-item` which I use to determine if an event will triggered when clicked.

The file contains this:

```
<div id="load-here">

</div>

<div class="item-1 menu-item">
    click this
</div>
```

I also have a gallery.html file which I want to be loaded into the main.html file in the `#load-here` div, and let's say it contains this:

```
<div class="menu-item>
    <!-- some image here -->
    <img href="img/1.jpg />
</div>
```

The script I have is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "div" ).click(function() {

        if ( $( this ).hasClass( "menu-item" ) ) {
            $("#load-here").load("gallery.html" + this.class);
        }

    });
});
```

The problem: It's not working. I've tried various changes. Somehow it's not loading into the `#load-here` div

Comment: Are you running this with web server or just opening that html file directly in the browser using `file://` ?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618865/load-part-page-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: There is no `this.class` .... is undefined. Even if there was it would include `"menu-item"` and space preceding it

Comment: Why do you add this.class to url? You can use this.className  but what is the idea?

Comment: @kabirbaidhya You are correct, I'm running it on file:// on my local environment. Does it not work with that?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to several issues:

1. By this: `$( "div" ).click(function() ...` you are registering the click on all `div`s available. This might cause strange behaviour. Better use: `$("div.menu-item").click( ...`
2. Make sure you understand the context and the event target in your callback function. Sometimes `this` is cheating you, as the context of the call may be different. Things are more clear if you handle the event as explicit parameter and check the event target.
3. I guess you would like to give a parameter for your gallery.html, but as  @charlietfl mentions, there is no `.class`. But, in the DOM there is a [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/className). Better try to use the jQuery `$().attr('class')`. Also, the parameter needs a separator: `gallery.html?parameter`

To sum it up, here my suggestion:

```
$("div.menu-item").click( function(event) { 

  var jqTarget = $(event.target).closest('.menu-item');

  if ( jqTarget.hasClass( "menu-item" ) ) {
    $("#load-here").load("gallery.html" + "?" + this.class);
  }

});
```

`closest()` will attempt to find the closest matching element, in case the click target was not on the `div` itself, but rather a child `img` or else. So, the condition in the suggestion should be used to find out about more specific about which menu item was clicked: `if ( jqTarget.hasClass( "that-specific-item" ) ...`