# AJAX HTML data is ok, but find returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm fetching an HTML document with $.get (tried $.ajax as well):

```
$.get('/products/', function(data) {
    $('.content .article').remove();
    $('.content').prepend($(data).find('.article'));
});
```

Checked if data is ok with:

```
alert(data);
```

And It prints the html file with no problem. But when I try to print:

```
alert($(data).find('.article').html());
```

or

```
alert($('.article', data).html());
```

It always prints null.

I found a similiar problem here: [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2137811), but the solutions didn't work for me.

EDIT:
Content o generated HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>

<div class="article"><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: You should be using the console for this, and you're sure you have an element with the class `article`, and that is not an element with the `article` tag ? Also, you are missing a quote on the top example after the last `.content` statement. Drop the `html()` function and try to find the element and `console.log` it directly.

Comment: Show us the contents of `data` please

Comment: You're probably just getting an HTML string back from your AJAX call where you really need an object.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure I have an .article class not using HTML5 yet. But I don't know how to use the console... =/ I'll try and study that.

Comment: Is it the root element that has the `article` class

Comment: @j08691 I guess you're right... but how do I configure to get an HTML, then? I tried setting dataType : 'html' or using $.get(url, func, 'html'), but the same problem happened.

Comment: @Ken In Chrome for example, press F12 and select console tab, there you will get the values from console.log(something); also you can make debug but thats other story.

Comment: I simplified my html to something like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
<div class="article">FOO</div>
<div class="nav"><!-- here goes a nav list I want to discard it --></div>
</body></html>

Comment: @Ken check my answer maybe could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(data).filter('.article');
```

That's what I get when I turn your data string into a jQuery object:

```
[div.article, div.nav]
```

Seems like when you convert a string which represents an whole HTML document, jQuery makes a collection of just the items inside the body.

Comment: That did the job! Thank you!
But, do you know why .filter is able to handle my output as html, and .find is not?

Comment: Find does handle it too. But the object converted from you HTML string already is the collection of the DOM elements which are inside `<body>`, so you try to `.find('.article')` in `$('.article')` and `$('.nav')`, which of course returns zero objects (find only looks for descendants). With `.filter('.article')` instead, you extract the objects needed from the given collection.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would be really good if you put the content of `data` but from what I got I can tell you these things...

---

First of all, you are missing a quote on the top example after the last `.content` statement.

Look here:

```
$('.content').prepend($(data).find('.article'));
```

correct it to:

```
$('.content').prepend($(data).find('.article'));
```

---

Then, try doing `console.log($(data));` and make sure your string is converted correctly to jQuery object.

Another thing, try doing `console.log($(data).find('.article'));` and make sure if it returns more than just one element because doing `.html()` from lots of elements may return `null`

And, If there is more than one element and supposing you just want the first, do this:

```
var articles = $(data).find('.article');
var firstArticle = articles.first().html();
```

or if you want to loop inside all articles, do this to get each `html`:

```
$.each($(data).find('.article'), function(index, value){
   console.log($(this).html());
});
```

---

If nothing works for you then I just can tell you to try checking whats the exact value of `data` as string before converting it to jQuery object.

---

### Solved

- Your `data` from the callback is composed like this when getting the `string` from the `/products/` page in the jQuery `$.get`:

[image]

- As you can see, when converting `data` to `$(data)` and trying to find `.article` will fail cause the object is not only composed from just one element.
- So your code has to be modified to this:

  ```
  $.get('/products/', function(data){
      $('.content .article').remove();
      $('.content').prepend($(data).eq(1));
  });
  ```
- Now everything will work because your code will find just the second element (the article html -- 1st element according to array index) from your object `$(data)` and then put it in your `.content` div.

Hope this helps :-) I tested and it is working.

**PS. Don't forget to always print elements, as I told you starting my answer, try doing `console.log($(data));` to know how it is composed!**

Comment: I tried $.get(/home/, function(data) { console.log($(data)) }); and the output was a Text type object. So I guess that's the problem. But how can I guarantee to get an HTML object instead?
I edited the question to show the HTML file.

Comment: It really worked, but I went for @Simon 's solution using .filter(), because it seems to be more generic, as in other pages of my site, could be other divs and not just article. But I'm very grateful for your effort, cause I learned how to check the situation of my variables with console.log(), and even studied how to debug in chrome. Thanks a lot! =)