# How to get a part of HTML webpage in a jQuery ajax Request? In other words how to filter the web page contents on an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the below script to load the html in my page. However it loads all of the page contents that is included in webpage.html means(from doctype to closing html tag).

```
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"webpage.html",
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("body").html(data);
                },
                error:function() {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
        });
```

I have no control over webpage.html, I actually just need a few divs with particular classes to load after an ajax Request. Can anyone give me some Idea as to how would I filter the webpage contents over an ajax Call for which I have no control.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 success:function(data) {
     var out = "";
     $(data).find("your selectors").each(function(loop, item){
         out += $(item).html();
     });
     data = out;
     alert(data);
     $("body").html(data);
 }
```

Comment: but I would loose my styling with that approach?

Comment: @Mike, use server language, to example `php`, and return custom data from server.

Comment: I have no control over the webpage. It is going to be cross domain.

Comment: Thanks, thats is quite useful, However I was wondering if it is possible to load the contents without an ajax call. I set up a fiddle if you can possibly help.  http://jsfiddle.net/TZRZh/2/

Comment: @Mike, with `js` and without ajax call? It's not possible. As I said above, use `server-side` language.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
var url = "webpage.html .classOfDivsYouWantLoaded";

$("body").load(url, function(){
    //callback after your data is in loaded into body.
});
```