# Extract piece of ajax request using jquery get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm struggling to get this get request to cooperate. I would like to begin by saying that the PHP side flawlessly. I am now trying to use ajax and jQuery to make it look smooth.

Here is the js:

```
$(".controls a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
        $(".schedule").fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).html(data).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

`$(this).attr("href")` refers to a URL that is passed in order to get information from a MySQL database (e.g. `hours.php?week=2014-08-11`). The value passed in `week` is updated via PHP every time a link is clicked.

Here is what I get from `console.log(data)` http://pastebin.com/bGpfjq6r

I've tried converting `data` (raw HTML) into a jQuery object by doing the following:

```
 var $data = $.parseHTML(data);
```

However, this just coverts the HTML into an array. I can perform a `find` for the element:

```
 console.log($($data).find(".schedule"));
```

but when I view the output of this the `context` is undefined.

I also tried the accepted answer in this question [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery) with no avail:

```
 var foo = $(".schedule", $data);
 console.log(foo);
```

This still has an undefined `context`.

Ideally, I want to grab just the information in `.section` and replacing the current in `.section` with the information captured from the GET request. `.section` is part of the `document` as well as what is returned from the request.

There are no errors in the console. jQuery version is 1.11.1.

My apologies if the question is poorly written. I tried to write it in a general way so it may apply to other people too. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: When you open your browser's developer tools are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Is `.schedule` in the current html document or in the returned data?

Comment: Shoot, my apologies. There are no errors in the console

Comment: @Sean `.schedule` is in the current document **and** the returned data

Comment: Is `.schedule` already in your HTML or is it contained within `data`?

Comment: What do you get for console.log(data);?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bGpfjq6r

Comment: Hmm, `.schedule` is already on page, you are injecting `<html> <head>` etc.. tags inside a div container, are you trying to update the entire page with new HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to replacing `.schedule` in the current document with `.schedule` retrieved from the request. `.schedule` is the only piece of the DOM that needs to be overridden. Hopefully that makes sense :x

Comment: Why not just get the contents of the `.schedule` div, I mean you are returning the whole HTML, and only using part of it. You could create a new file that contains just elements inside `.schedule` and then with one line in jQuery `$('.schedule').html(data);`

Comment: @PalinDrome555 I did as you recommended but the ajax call only works once. If I click on Next week twice it goes from [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bd3b6qc8b) to [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/02b3b6qice) where the only thing in the DOM is the `.schedule` HTML

Comment: It seems that the css `<style>` is not loaded, include all css files and js files on the page which you are calling the request from. You could put the `<style>` block inside data into an external css and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery filter() function.

```
$(".controls a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
        $(".schedule").fadeOut(200, function() {

            // apply filter function here to find new schedule div
            var newSchedule = $(data).filter(".schedule").eq(0).html();

            $(this).html(newSchedule).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Literally copied and pasted your code and it works once (from 8/11 to 8/18) before the js stops working without error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the response so you can parse it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Create named function to Initialize the on click event capture
    function initAJAX() {
        $(".controls a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                var response = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');
                var contents = response.find('.schedule').html()
                $(".schedule").fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $(this).html(contents).fadeIn(200);
                    // After we get the content updated, we have to reinitialize those new anchors
                    initAJAX();
                });
            });
        });
    }
    // We have to call this once to start or nothing will happen
    initAJAX();
});
```

Comment: It is only able to work once before the js stops working with no errors. Any ideas? [http://pastebin.com/9mgQjUuS](http://pastebin.com/9mgQjUuS)

Comment: Edited to address your problem and added comments.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. It has the same behavior.