# jquery element from another page with $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pull in a  element from another page with the id = usertags. I am usying the .get method.

For some reason I am unable to make it happen, no errors.

```
$.get('/cgi-bin/koha/opac-tags.pl', function(data) {
    var tags = $(data).find("#usertags");
    $("#mainuserblock").append(tags);
    console.log( $(data) );
});
```

I am mostly confused by what the log info $(data) says. To me it looks like it is not actually pulling from the opac-tags.pl page but from somewhere else:

```
{
  "length": 0,
  "prevObject": {
    "0": {
      "auth": {
        "0": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {}
        },
        "1": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {}
        }
      },
      "searchform": {
        "0": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {},
          "6": {}
        },
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
      },
      "location": {
        "href": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
        "origin": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "protocol": "http:",
        "host": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "hostname": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "port": "",
        "pathname": "/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
        "search": "",
        "hash": ""
      }
    },
    "context": {
      "auth": {
        "0": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {}
        },
        "1": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {}
        }
      },
      "searchform": {
        "0": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {},
          "6": {}
        },
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
      },
      "location": {
        "href": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
        "origin": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "protocol": "http:",
        "host": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "hostname": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
        "port": "",
        "pathname": "/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
        "search": "",
        "hash": ""
      }
    },
    "length": 1
  },
  "context": {
    "auth": {
      "0": {
        "0": {},
        "1": {},
        "2": {},
        "3": {},
        "4": {}
      },
      "1": {
        "0": {},
        "1": {},
        "2": {},
        "3": {},
        "4": {},
        "5": {}
      }
    },
    "searchform": {
      "0": {
        "0": {},
        "1": {},
        "2": {},
        "3": {},
        "4": {},
        "5": {},
        "6": {}
      },
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "location": {
      "href": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
      "origin": "http://viu.bywatersolutions.com",
      "protocol": "http:",
      "host": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
      "hostname": "viu.bywatersolutions.com",
      "port": "",
      "pathname": "/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl",
      "search": "",
      "hash": ""
    }
  },
  "selector": "response = {\n\tadded: 0,\n\tdeleted: 0,\n\terrors: 0\n\n\n};"
}
```

Any one ever experienced anything like this?

Comment: `console.log(data)` without the $() around data and see what it prints out.

Comment: Thanks taplar! that is what I did, see the 2nd part of code. thats the console.log. which seems to me to be from the /cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl and not the /cgi-bin/koha/user-tags.pl. which is what a referenced in the initial jquery.

Comment: If you read my quote, I said *without* surrounding the data with $().  your console log has the $() in it

Comment: Could be a lot of reasons. Without knowing the setup of the page you are pulling. As already suggested, `console.log(data)` in addition does your other page rely on JavaScript to be executed to generate the elements? If so, `$.get()` does **not** execute scripts on the page retrieved. Is your identifier is misspelled? Could a number of reasons.

Comment: Also you should be able to do this with just `$("#mainuserblock").load('/cgi-bin/koha/opac-tags.pl #usertags');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Exactly - I have done something like this that exact way before.

Comment: Your `opac-tags.pl` is *not* returning HTML, but you are using it as if it is.

Comment: You could try specifying the type on the `$.get`, eg `$.get(url, success, "html")`

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137850/9305209).

Basically, you should pass HTML context as the second argument of `$`:

```
$("#usertags", data);
```

Alternatively, this syntax should also work:

```
$("#mainuserblock").load("/cgi-bin/koha/opac-tags.pl #usertags");
```

but it will overwrite previous contents of `#mainuserblock`.