# How to get authorization code when user redirect to callback url using Jquery. AJAX call returns HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

```
$.ajax({
    uri: "https://access.line.me/oauth2/v2.1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=Chanel_Id&redirect_uri=https://manager.line.biz/&state=none&scope=profile%20openid",
    type: "POST",
    
    xhr: function() {
            return xhr;
       },
    success: function(data, status){
      window.open(auth_URL, '_blank');
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(xhr.responseXML);
      console.log(xhr.responseURL);
      console.log(status);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("error");
    }
    
});
```

Comment: I'm missing a bit context. Do I understand it right that, you're making an AJAX request and it is redirecting to an authorization page instead of returning the result from the web service?

Comment: Yes, It is redirecting to authorization page and that page contains callback URL with query parameters

Comment: Let's use the assumption, that your setup is correct and the redirect will always happen. In that case you'd need to do two requests. You'd do the first to get the URL and still inside the callback, you'd do the second AJAX request with the new URL.

Comment: No, I didn't do the second AJAX request. how it could be possible?

Comment: In the `success` function grab the URL and then add a new `$.ajax({...});`

Comment: I could not able to grab the URL. How to grab it?

Comment: Have a look if this is helping you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery

Comment: .load() does not returning anything.

Comment: Again, I'm missing some context here. Could you update your question with some more code, error messages and a bit more explanations? I know creating something that would be reproducible will be difficult given the fact that one needs to authenticate. If you have trouble on how to complete the question, could you have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?